# OpenCV Camera Stereo Calibration - Strange results

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I am trying to calibrate my Minoru stereo camera with OpenCV. The following code first calibrates the camera and then rectifies the results. When I run the code, the rectification results are somehow strange. 
I've attached one of the results. 
It would be very helpful, if somebody could look over my code. 
Thanks Max

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>
#include "libcam.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void loadImagePair(Mat &img1, Mat &img2, int i) {

    stringstream ss1, ss2;

    ss1 << "data/saves/" << i << "_1.png";
    ss2 << "data/saves/" << i << "_2.png";

    /*if (i < 10) {
     ss1 << "data/martinperris_images/left0" << i << ".ppm";
     ss2 << "data/martinperris_images/right0" << i << ".ppm";
     } else {
     ss1 << "data/martinperris_images/left" << i << ".ppm";
     ss2 << "data/martinperris_images/right" << i << ".ppm";
     }*/

    img1 = imread(ss1.str());
    img2 = imread(ss2.str());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // The camera properties
    int w = 640;
    int h = 480;
    int fps = 20;

    // The chessboard properties
    CvSize chessboardSize(9, 6);
    float squareSize = 1.0f;

    // This should contain the physical location of each corner, but since we don't know them, we are assigning constant positions
    vector<vector<Point3f> > objPoints;
    // The chessboard corner points in the images
    vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints1, imagePoints2;
    vector<Point2f> corners1, corners2;

    // The constant positions of each obj points
    vector<Point3f> obj;
    for (int x = 0; x < chessboardSize.width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < chessboardSize.height; y++) {
            obj.push_back(Point3f(x * squareSize, y * squareSize, 0));
        }
    }
    /*for (int i = 0; i < chessboardSize.width * chessboardSize.height; i++) {
     obj.push_back(Point3f(i / chessboardSize.width, i % chessboardSize.height, 0.0f));
     }*/

    // The images, which are proceeded
    Mat img1, img2;
    // The grayscale versions of the images
    Mat gray1, gray2;

    // Get the image count
    int imageCount;
    cout << "How much images to load: " << endl;
    cin >> imageCount;
    // The image number of the current image (nullbased)
    int i = 0;
    // Whether the chessboard corners in the images were found
    bool found1 = false, found2 = false;

    while (i < imageCount) {

        // Load the images
        cout << "Attempting to load image pair " << i << endl;
        loadImagePair(img1, img2, i);
        cout << "Loaded image pair" << endl;

        // Convert to grayscale images
        cvtColor(img1, gray1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cvtColor(img2, gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        // Find chessboard corners
        found1 = findChessboardCorners(img1, chessboardSize, corners1, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);
        found2 = findChessboardCorners(img2, chessboardSize, corners2, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

        cout << "found 1/2: " << found1 << "/" << found2 << endl;

        // Find corners to subpixel accuracy
        if (found1) {
            cornerSubPix(gray1, corners1, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(gray1, chessboardSize, corners1, found1);
        }
        if (found2) {
            cornerSubPix(gray2, corners2, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
            drawChessboardCorners(gray2, chessboardSize, corners2, found2);
        }

        // Store corners
        if (found1 && found2) {
            imagePoints1.push_back(corners1);
            imagePoints2.push_back(corners2);
            objPoints.push_back(obj);
            cout << "Corners stored" << endl;
            i++;
        }
        // Error
        else {
            cout << "Corners not found! Stopping" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "Starting calibration" << endl;
    Mat CM1 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Mat CM2 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Mat D1 = Mat(1, 5, CV_64F);
    Mat D2 = Mat(1, 5, CV_64F);
    Mat R = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Mat T = Mat(3, 1, CV_64F);
    Mat E = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Mat F = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    //stereoCalibrate(objPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, E, F,
    //CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH | CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST, cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5));
    stereoCalibrate(objPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, E, F, 0,
            cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5));
    cout << "Done calibration" << endl;

    cout << "Starting rectification" << endl;
    Mat R1 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Mat R2 = Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Mat P1 = Mat(3, 4, CV_64F);
    Mat P2 = Mat(3, 4, CV_64F);
    Mat Q = Mat(4, 4, CV_64F);
    stereoRectify(CM1, D1, CM2, D2, img1.size(), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q);
    cout << "Done rectification" << endl;

    cout << "Starting to store results" << endl;
    FileStorage fs("stereocalib.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << "CM1" << CM1;
    fs << "CM2" << CM2;
    fs << "D1" << D1;
    fs << "D2" << D2;
    fs << "R" << R;
    fs << "T" << T;
    fs << "E" << E;
    fs << "F" << F;
    fs << "R1" << R1;
    fs << "R2" << R2;
    fs << "P1" << P1;
    fs << "P2" << P2;
    fs << "Q" << Q;
    fs.release();
    cout << "Done storing results" << endl;

    cout << "Starting to apply undistort" << endl;
    Mat map1x = Mat(img1.size().height, img1.size().width, CV_32F);
    Mat map1y = Mat(img1.size().height, img1.size().width, CV_32F);
    Mat map2x = Mat(img2.size().height, img2.size().width, CV_32F);
    Mat map2y = Mat(img2.size().height, img2.size().width, CV_32F);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(CM1, D1, R1, P1, img1.size(), CV_32FC1, map1x, map1y);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(CM2, D2, R2, P2, img2.size(), CV_32FC1, map2x, map2y);
    cout << "Done applying undistort" << endl;

    // The rectified images
    Mat imgU1 = Mat(img1.size(), img1.type()), imgU2 = Mat(img2.size(), img2.type());

    // Show rectified images
    i = 0;
    while (i < imageCount) {

        // Load the images
        cout << "Attempting to load image pair " << i << endl;
        loadImagePair(img1, img2, i);
        cout << "Loaded image pair" << endl;
        i++;

        remap(img1, imgU1, map1x, map1y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
        remap(img2, imgU2, map2x, map2y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());
        //remap(img1, imgU1, map1x, map1y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_DEFAULT);
        //remap(img2, imgU2, map2x, map2y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_DEFAULT);

        imshow("img1", img1);
        imshow("img2", img2);
        imshow("rec1", imgU1);
        imshow("rec2", imgU2);

        int key = waitKey(0);
        if (key == 'q') {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: yea, that's a bad calibration result. please check the return value of stereoCalibrate, if it's beyond say 0.5, - you'll have to do it all again, giving better(more diverse) poses. what's your imageCount ? you'll need about a good dozen.

Comment: My calibration result is 109.023, I think this is pretty bad. I am using 30 images from different perspectives.
Do you known any ways to increase the calibration quality or do I give wrong parameters?
As you may also see from my code I tried the images from Martin Perris Blog(http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/01/opencv-stereo-camera-calibration.html). The results with these images were also very bad.

Comment: all i know, is that this might be one of the most painful things you'll encounter ever. (the sum of) your poses should cover the whole visible area, each pic should be as sharp as possible(nooo, don't readjust the focus !!), also, the usual samples also use cornerSubPix or what it was called ... given that distance, you maybe want a larger board, too.

Comment: Is there a variation in depth too, or is the chessboard in the same plane for all images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out, what the problem was. The images were good, but I defined the obj Vector the wrong way. It has to be:

```
    // The constant positions of each obj points
    vector<Point3f> obj;
    for (int y = 0; y < chessboardSize.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < chessboardSize.width; x++) {
            obj.push_back(Point3f(y * squareSize, x * squareSize, 0));
        }
    }
```

Now I have a calibration result of 1.57324, which is quite good I think.

Comment: Common mistake, opencv Mat are specified by number of rows first - it's the only efficient way to grow them - the logic carriers over into lots of other fucntions